# ember how to display relationship property in template

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a ember data model like this:

```
var attr = DS.attr,
    hasMany = DS.hasMany,
    belongsTo = DS.belongsTo;
App.Message = DS.Model.extend({
    partner_pk: attr(),
    message: attr(),
    user: belongsTo('user', {async: true}),
    inquiry: belongsTo('inquiry', {async: true}),
    created_at: attr(),
    updated_at: attr()
});
```

and route returning array of data like this:

```
App.TripMessagesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(){
        return this.store.find('message', {inquiry_id: 2});
    }
})
```

My rest-api return data like this format:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 10,
            "message": "this message is updated by ember.js",
            "inquiry_id": 2,
            "user_id": 1,
            "created_at": "2014-08-05 14:20:46",
            "updated_at": "2014-08-05 14:20:46"
        },
        {
            "id": 17,
            "message": "this is a test message by ember.js",
            "inquiry_id": 2,
            "user_id": 39,
            "created_at": "2014-08-26 17:34:55",
         }
      ]
}
```

in my template I am displaying the properties like this:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="trip/messages">
    <h2>message is: {{message}}</h2> <!-- This works fine -->
    <h2>User id: {{log user}}</h2> <!-- it gives  null -->
    <h2>User id: {{log user_id}}</h2> <!-- it gives  undefined -->
</script>
```

My question is how do I display **user_id** in my template. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

By default the property name in your Model definition should match the property being returned in your JSON.

Your choices are...

- change your model to look like `user_id: belongsTo('user', {async: true})`
- change your JSON to look like `"user_id": 39`
- Add a MessageSerializer and change the object from `user_id` to `user` in the serializer.

You should then be able to put something like `{{user.id}}` in your template.